# Extract a file from an old commit to a path outside my working directory

Tags: git

I have a working directory at `~/gitrepo/` (this is where `.git` folder is, and all my other files as usual).

I have an old commit whose SHA-1 hash I know. In it there was a file `foo.cpp` that I now want to bring back to **another directory** (just to not mess up my working tree), for instance here:

`~/Desktop/foo.cpp`

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git checkout SHA -- foo.cpp
cp foo.cpp ~/Descktop/foo.cpp
```

After that you'll have edited `foo.cpp` , so you may wanna revert it back with `git reset` or something.

Comment: what if a later `foo.cpp` already exists? don't wanna overwrite that one... instead i'd like to get the older one to an independent location.

Comment: `git checkout` could «apply» specified commit state to all files. Also it could do that for selected files (with power of `--`). It there will be some problems - git'll tell you and you could use `-f` to force some changes. I advise to do these manipulations with clear stage for more safety and clearness.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your commit on github website, and download the file you want from there.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get an old copy of an Informix 4GL file. First, I copied re_trnfunc.4gl to re_trnfunc.4gl.sav, because I had never tried this before.

Then, I entered:

`git log --shortstat --pretty`

I looked for the commitment that corresponded to the comment that told me which version I wanted.

```
commit 6fbe9303e7f80150fdf6abdc8f926a802f8a171e
Author: Charles M. Norton <someone@somewhereville.com>
Date:   Wed Jul 1 14:13:58 2015 -0400

    Put in new re payment distro order, interest, charges, and principal.

 1 files changed, 34 insertions(+), 30 deletions(-)
```

Then I entered (as shown in @ДМИТРИЙ МАЛИКОВ 's answer)

`git checkout 6fbe9303e7f80150fdf6abdc8f926a802f8a171e -- re_trnfunc.4gl`

I examined the file, saved it elsewhere, and then needed to put re_trnfunc.4gl the way it was before the checkout.

I entered:

`git reset HEAD re_trnfunc.4gl`

I could have eliminated having to reset by checking out the file to a temp name after the `--` in the

`git checkout 6fbe9303e7f80150fdf6abdc8f926a802f8a171e -- temp_re_trnfunc.4gl`

command.